# Deflection of light according to Eddington

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

I am reading a text by Arthur Eddington in which, among other things, he computed the deflection of light by a star in general relativity (I paste the relevant page at the bottom).

I am not looking to understand light deflection per se, I want to understand what Eddington says.

Using the Schwarzschild metric, he arrives at the equation $$v^2=1-\frac{4m}{r},$$ relating the speed of light to radial distance. This feels strange because speed would increase with distance, while intuitively it should decrease since it is being attracted. In other words, when compared to the energy equation of a newtonian Kepler system $v^2=E+1/r$ (without centrifugal barrier) it has the wrong sign.

Anyway, then he turns a trick that leaves me completely confused. He starts by saying that the above equation describes a light ray propagating in a medium with variable refraction coefficient $\mu=1+2m/r$. Finally, he notices that $$\mu^2\approx 1+\frac{4m}{r},$$ and says that THIS is the equation of a particle of velocity $\mu$ in a newtonian attractive gravitational field.

But $\mu$ was the refraction coefficient, then all of a sudden it turns into the velocity?? I mean, the statement might be correct, but $\mu$ is not really the velocity, so I don't see how he derived a conclusion about the actual trajectory.

[image]

Comment: The phase velocity of a wave in a medium with refractive index $\mu$ is $v = c/\mu$ so yes, the two are (inversely) related.

Comment: Right, but then he says "a particle with velocity $\mu$". This is what I don't understand

Comment: That's a formal identification ("the same equations have the same solutions"): he notices that the $\mu$ equations look just like the equations of a particle under the attraction of a mass $2m$, if he makes the formal identification $\mu \equiv v$. Since he knows the solution of the $v$ equations, he now knows the solution of the $\mu$ equations: they are the same equations under the formal identification, so they have the same solutions.

Comment: He is saying that the trajectory would be a hyperbola for a particle with velocity $\mu$. This is fine. But $\mu$ is not the actual velocity, and yet he then claims that a hyperbola is the actual trajectory. He says: "This hyperbola, therefore, gives the path of the light". No, this hyperbola would give the path of the light if the light had velocity $\mu$, which it does not.